# limited threads in soapUI free version

Tags: soapui, load-testing

We have been using **soapUI free version (4.5.1)** for a long time in our project to test our web services. We mostly used simple strategy along with different thread counts to check the load of our servers and web services. We used 50, 75, 100 and 150 thread to check how many connections that our web service can handle. We used no delay and therefore, no random to have constant threads.

After our servers went down, system experts arrived today and told us that soapUI does not **really** creates threads as entered (i.e. 100). They argued that the free version updates and sets the thread count to 5 (or something lower or higher) instead of our desired value. This really shocked us because we tested our project with free version and did not use any other test tool to cross-check.

So, what I am trying to ask is, is it true that I can create only limited threads and not use, say, 150 threads in the free version of soapUI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that is not true.

It wouldn't make sense for SoapUI to have such a restriction since it's open source; so anyone could fork SoapUI and remove the restriction from the source code.

This confusion might be because there was a bug limiting the number of threads in SoapUI 4.5.0 (both Open Source and Pro version). This bug is fixed in 4.5.1

*Source/disclaimer: I'm a developer working full time on LoadUI and SoapUI.*

Comment: Thank you very much. This will remove all doubts.