# Spring Web Service Endpoint on Tomcat - concurrent calls configuration

Tags: multithreading, spring-mvc, tomcat7, spring-integration

I have a Spring application with a Web Service `Endpoint` which, upon receiving a call, will pass the request payload to a Spring Integration `MessagingGateway` for EIP processing.

My application is deployed on a `Tomcat 7` container and is built using Spring 4 APIs.

I am trying to run a performance test where I make multiple concurrent calls to the web service. When I perform this test, each request is processed okay and a response is successfully received back for each request made but, the Spring application seems to only be handling two requests at the time. i.e. the third request is only processed by the application once the second request's response is sent back to the client. (When debugging I can see that there are only ever two threads handling requests)

I would like to know where my Spring application's execution thread configuration should be done in order to support handling of multiple web service client requests concurrently (e.g. 10+ concurrent threads). Should this be done somewhere in the Tomcat container's configuration? Somewhere in the Web Service's configuration? Spring Integration's Messaging gateway configuration? Spring Integration's request integration flow configuration? A combination of some of these configurations? Or somewhere else entirely?

My stack is:

```
Tomcat 7.0.55
Spring/Integration 4 APIs
Spring Java DSL 1 API
```

For my test, I am using SoapUI 4.5.0 and I am carrying out a load test with the following configuration:

`Threads: 10, Strategy: Thread, Start Threads: 10, End Threads: 10, Limit 1 Runs per thread.`

I am assuming that this configuration is okay for testing 10 concurrent calls to a web service URL...

*** UPDATED TO INCLUDE CURRENT CONFIGURATIONS ***

Endpoint configuration:

```
@Endpoint
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.test.gateway")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.company.test.gateway")
public class TestServiceEndpoint {

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://www.company.com/test";

    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();

    @Autowired
    private TestGateway gateway;

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "test")
    @ResponsePayload
    public TestResponse process(
            @RequestPayload TestRequest request) throws Exception {

        TestResponse response = gateway.process(request);

        return response;
    }
}
```

Gateway configuration:

```
@MessagingGateway
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public interface TestGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "test.request.ch", replyChannel = "test.response.ch")
    TestResponse process(TestRequest request);
}
```

Integration configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Bean(name = "test.request.ch")
    public DirectChannel testRequestCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean(name = "test.response.ch")
    public DirectChannel testResponseCh() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(10);
        return executor;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow requestFlow() {

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from("test.request.ch")
                .enrichHeaders(
                        m -> {
                            m.header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL,
                                    "test.error.ch", true);
                        })
                .handle("testSplitter", "split")
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor("requestSplitterFlowExecutor",
                        this.taskExecutor()))
                .route("testRouter", "route")
                        .get();
    }

    ...
}
```

Cheers,
PM

Comment: You need to show your integration configuration. If you are using `DirectChannel`s throughout, the integration flow will run on the tomcat http threads which should not be limited to 2.

Comment: Hi Gary, the channels directly associated with the gateway are `DirectChannel`s. Further down the flow however, things get a little more complicated depending on how the message is routed. In the perf test I am currently running, the `testRouter` will route the payload to a `PublishSubscribeChannel` where the payload is placed in an MQ queue. The reason this is a pub-sub channel is that we do other work once we know the payload has successfully been put in the queue. Thereafter, the response eventually arrives via a `JMS Inbound Adapter` and sent to the `test.response.ch` back to the Gateway.

Comment: There's nothing in the framework then, that should limit your threads. I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging and follow the message flow; be sure to include the thread name (`%t` if log4j) so you can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the application was processing messages only two at the time (sometimes even just one ata time!) was NOT because of a problem in Spring configurations or Tomcat configurations at all, but because of a bug in the test tool SoapUI 4.5.0. See [limited threads in soapUI free version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897839/limited-threads-in-soapui-free-version).

After updating SoapUI and re-running, messages can now be seen being processed by many threads at a time.